# How is the Stable Marriage problem $O(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms

I have read online notes and it says that the worst case scenario is $$O(n^2)$$ because there are $n$ men and $n$ women, and hence there is $n^2$ pairs. However, I just tried making a preference list for men and women and no matter what combination I try I never get all $n^2$ possible pairs..

For example, when $n=5$, the most pairs I could get was $21$, not $25$. So how is the worst case $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Do you remember the definition of what $O(\cdots)$ means? There's an arbitrary constant factor in there. A function can be less than $n^2$ for all inputs and still be $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: I kind of remember now, what you are saying is that it doesn't have to be exactly O(n^2), but in some cases for other algorithms it can reach exactly n^2 iterations. I forgot about that and was fixated on the idea that it must reach n^2 iterations for it to be a an upper bound